# How to publish solution into Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, publish

I have solution with multiple projects

```
project.Core - business logic 
project.Data - Entity Framework context (Code First) - has connection string
project.Domain - models
project.Web - MVC
```

I created project in azure portal with db. Then try to publish [image: No db founs]

The problem is: No Database found in the project. 
How to find it?

Comment: Have you found why the db settings are missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can ignore that and try publish it. But you'll need to create a database on Azure, so you application can talk to a real database. If you are using local storage, you'll be fine without this "Databases" section.

This part of web-deploy deals with database connection strings. If you have a connection string in  `web.config` and have `.Release` transformation, again this "Databases" section can be ignored.

Comment: Do you know what makes it appear/not appear?